# Why there is no PlaceHolder like property in XAML TextBox

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any **"placeholder type"** property availble for textbox in xaml in windows phone 8

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is the PhoneTextBox in the official [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/), covered [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-phonetextbox-in-depth).

Sample code:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="Password"/>
```

[image]

To add toolkit to your project :
Type the following into your package manager console :
`PM> Install-Package WPtoolkit`
And

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

inside `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage` tag in the `xaml` page

Comment: VerticalContentAlignment="Top" doesn't work? anyone know how to make it vertical align top (the text that is)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the hint text when the texbox recieve the focus??

Answer (score 1):

There is no placeholder property for TextBox. I use the following solution to work around this for a username textbox:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="UsernamePlaceholder" Text="Username" />
    <TextBox Name="UsernameTextBox" Text="" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{    
    UsernamePlaceholder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox)
    {
        var textbox = sender as TextBox;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
        {
            UsernamePlaceholder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

This basically replaces the TextBox with a Grid-element, containing a TextBox and a TextBlock (working as placeholder). Then when the textbox is focused, the textblock is hidden, and when it looses focus the textblock is shown if the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this below code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InvoiceDate" Text="" Width="300"  TextAlignment="Left" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Men att läsa" Width="300"  TextAlignment="Left" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="5, 5, 5, 5"  Foreground="LightGray">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=InvoiceDate}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>                                    
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on the answer of PKENO

**XAML (UserControl):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="FestivalProject.Controls.TextBoxPH"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"            
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <TextBox x:Name="testTextBox" Margin="0" LostFocus="testTextBox_LostFocus" GotFocus="testTextBox_GotFocus"/>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind UserControl:**

```
public partial class TextBoxPH : UserControl
    {
        private String _Text;

        public String Text
        {
            get { return _Text; }
            set { 
                _Text = testTextBox.Text = value;               
            }
        }



        private String _PlaceHolder;
        public String PlaceHolder
        {
            get { return _PlaceHolder; }
            set { 
                _PlaceHolder =testTextBox.Text = value;      
            }
        }        

        public TextBoxPH()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();  
        }   

        private void testTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testTextBox.Text)) testTextBox.Text = PlaceHolder;              

        }

        private void testTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (testTextBox.Text.Equals(PlaceHolder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) testTextBox.Text = string.Empty;

        }
    }
```

**XAML (in Window):**

```
<txtPH:TextBoxPH  Margin="5"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" PlaceHolder="PlaceholderText"/>
```

Probably not the most efficient way, but it works.