# Watermark effect on TextBox in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, textbox

How do I create text box with watermark effect in windows phone?
I have two text boxes

1. Username
2. Password

Now I want that in first text box, Username  by default written in light weight and If I write in that text box, it should be disappear. How to solve it?

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15759169/17447

Comment: @naveen thank you man!!stay blessed

Comment: You could search a little on internet before asking your question, a quick research on google and you have you find the answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use PhoneTextBox from windows phone toolkit for this.

1. You can download it from [here.](https://phone.codeplex.com/)
2. You can also directly add it to your project by typing the following into your package manager console :

   PM> Install-Package WPtoolkit

Now, add a reference of toolkit inside "phone:PhoneApplicationPage" tag in the xaml page as follows:
   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

Finally, use PhoneTextBox control.

`<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="Username"/>`

Comment: thanks man..keep it up brother